# Why use a return when calling parent?

Tags: php

I am learning OO PHP and I was experimenting with using a parent::method in a child class. I noticed i had to use an "extra" **return** for the output of the parent method to show up. *Could someone explain me why this is?*

This is the code I used and in the code I made a comment.

```php
class ShopProduct {

    public $productnumber;

    public function __construct($productnumber) {
        $this->productnumber = $productnumber;
    }
    public function getSummary(){
        return $this->productnumber;
    }
}

class BookProduct extends ShopProduct {

    public function __construct($productnumber) {
        parent::__construct($productnumber);
    }
    public function getSummary() {
        return parent::getSummary(); // if i dont use return it doesnt work? why is that?
        // parent::getSummary(); is not enough it seems.
    }
}

$product = new BookProduct(11111);
echo $product->getSummary();
?>
```

Comment: Well, if you don't do something with that value that the parent method returns, what do you expect? return doesn't print anything to the output buffer. So you're calling the function inside your extended class, however, the extended class does nothing with that function. as the return of your child function takes precedence over the parent function.

Comment: `getSummary()` should return a value, and in this case it just returns the value of `parent::getSummary()`. You can of course override the child's `getSummary()`.

Comment: The very last line of my code uses the method and Echo's it. Therefor I was expecting the value. In the parent class method the value is returned, so I was expecting it to inherit that "return"-behaviour in the child method too, because I called the parent method from the child. IF someone could use more words to explain that it would be most helpful.

Comment: If so you can remove the whole definition of the `public function getSummary()` in your child class. Once you add definition for it, that means you want to override the method (to add custom behavior or return a different value other than the `parent::getSummary()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public function getSummary() {
>     return parent::getSummary(); // if i dont use return it doesnt work? why is that?
>     // parent::getSummary(); is not enough it seems.
> }
> ```

Replace `parent::getSummary()` with any other function or method call:

```
public function getSummary() {
    foo();
}
```

Of course you wouldn't expect `getSummary` to return anything in this case, right? Just because the method you're calling is `parent::...` doesn't change anything about this behaviour. It does not `return` automagically, because you may want to do something like this:

```
public function getSummary() {
    $summary = parent::getSummary();
    return "Book: $summary";
}
```

BTW, if the only thing your method does is call its parent, you can leave out the entire method. In other words, this:

```
class BookProduct extends ShopProduct {

    public function __construct($productnumber) {
        parent::__construct($productnumber);
    }
    public function getSummary() {
        return parent::getSummary();
    }
}
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
class BookProduct extends ShopProduct { }
```

Comment: Thanks Deceze, I am using a book, I think they try to walk through all the concepts. That is probably why my example seems a bit redundant. My question is focusing on "why" I should use "return" Twice. At least that's what my brain is telling me. I, as a (novice) expect the "return" that the parent method uses to be inherited by the child method. I seem to be mistaken about that, but I try to understand why that is. (i am using an echo at the last line so that I do expect something to output not?)

Comment: Ok i think I understand what you are saying thanks to the second example! I Thought maybe the OO magic brought more than I expected. I appreciate your time and explanation!